# CodeIgniter - Error de sintaxe com select e where

Tags: php, codeigniter

Em um projeto preciso que aparece apenas as publicações ativas na página principal estou usando Codeigniter, usei as seguintes linhas de código:

```
Model:

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from("publicacoes");
$this->db->where('ativacao' == '1');
$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

return $data;
```

Porém quando deixo essa linha "descomentada" a aplicação "quebra"

```
$this->db->where('ativacao' == '1');
```

Comment: Só uma dica, em vez de você usar a linha do from, já pode colocar o nome da tabela dentro do get ficando assim: $this->db->get('publicacoes')->result_array();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere `$this->db->where('ativacao' == '1');` para `$this->db->where("ativacao = '1'");`

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou +1

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação no site do Codeigniter, a forma "ideal" de se fazer isso seria assim:

```
$this->db->where('ativacao' , '1');
```

e quando você for usar um `where <>` aí fica

```
$this->db->where('ativacao <>' , '1');
```

Comment: +1 Muito Obrigada pela informação